# How to autohide the Bokeh toolbar when using holoviews

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews, hvplot

The holoviews documentation mentions that the Bokeh toolbar can be hidden or moved: http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Plotting_with_Bokeh.html
The bokeh document shows how to autohide the toolbar so it only shows on mouse-over.

Is it possible to autohide the toolbar when using holoviews as it doesn't allow me to pass options like `toolbar='autohide'`

Any help would be most welcome.

```py
fundYear.hvplot.bar(
    x='year',
    y='fundingReq',
    rot=90,
).opts(
    toolbar='left',
    title="Funding Requested per Year",
    yformatter='$%f',
)
```

Comment: Note that Bokeh doesn't currently support hiding the toolbar from a multi-plot layout, so any HoloViews-based solution will be limited to single plots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible settings for the position of the toolbar are:

> ['above', 'below', 'left', 'right', 'disable', None]

So you can't set autohide like that, but...

**1) You can use [hooks](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Customizing_Plots.html#Plot-hooks) to set autohide.** 

With hooks you can customize the plot just before it will be plotted.

```py
def set_toolbar_autohide(plot, element):
    bokeh_plot = plot.state
    bokeh_plot.toolbar.autohide = True

your_plot.opts(hooks=[set_toolbar_autohide], backend='bokeh')
```

You can also find useful info on hooks in the FAQ:
https://holoviews.org/FAQ.html

**2) Another solution would be to convert your Holoviews plot to an actual bokeh plot and then set the bokeh toolbar to autohide:**

**Quick solution is basically:**

```py
my_bokeh_plot = hv.render(my_hv_plot, backend='bokeh')
my_bokeh_plot.toolbar.autohide = True
```

**Full working example of 2nd solution:**

```py
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import holoviews as hv
import hvplot.pandas
hv.extension('bokeh', logo=False)

from bokeh.plotting import show


# create sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': np.random.normal(size=30),
    'col2': np.random.normal(size=30),
})

# create holoviews plot
my_hv_plot = df.hvplot.scatter(label='Scattering around', width=700)

# turn plot into bokeh plot
my_bokeh_plot = hv.render(my_hv_plot, backend='bokeh')

# set toolbar to autohide
my_bokeh_plot.toolbar.autohide = True

# show plot
show(my_bokeh_plot)
```